# Inserting UTF-8 data into SQL Server 2012

Tags: javascript, sql-server, utf-8

I have an SQL Server 2012 DB where a table contains 2 columns of UTF-8 data (non-English. Tamil language to be specific). The data type that I set for those columns are nvarchar(500). I get input (the UTF-8 data) from a jsp page (input type as text). I can insert the values of that text box into the sql server successfully, but when I went to see the value, it is like this "&#2...1;" I've also made sure to add N before the column value. Here's the code:

```js
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pass);

String addbks = "insert into something.dbo." + Table + " (ID, BookName, Author, Owner, OwnerEmpID, Status, Reservation, Genre, StatusID) values (NEXT VALUE FOR " + Seq + ", N'" + BookName + "', N'" + AuthorName + "', '" + Name + "', '" + user2 + "', 'Available', NULL, '" + Genre + "', '1')";
```

Where BookName and AuthorName are the two columns that we talked about. I have also converted the BookName and AuthorName into UTF-8 format - here's the code:

```js
BookName = new String(BookName.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
AuthorName = new String(AuthorName.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
```

Below the Body tag, I also have the following:

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

I still get special characters in the DB rather than the actual data. How can I achive this?

EDIT: For the record, if I insert the data directly in SQL Server, it works just fine. Here's the query:

```js
select BookName, Author from tam_hist where bookname like N'%தமிழ்%'
```

Result: தண்ணீர்

Comment: Did you check what collaction your SQL Server ir using?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: How do I check which collaction is my SQL Server using? Any query?

Comment: I used this query and found 75 rows in my DB.

SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() 
WHERE name LIKE 'SQL%';

Comment: You can check your collation using this query: `SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));`

Comment: This is the output: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after our little chat in comment section, I understood that your collaction needs to be changed in your table, this is potential query to do that:

```
ALTER TABLE tam_hist
ALTER COLUMN bookname NVARCHAR(500) COLLATE Indic_General_90_BIN;
```

I'm using this collation as it's suggested on [this site](http://forums.asp.net/t/1198680.aspx?sql%20collation%20for%20tamil%20language).

If you need/want to change collation on whole database, not on specific columns, please read [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx).

This is basic replication of your issue:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE ( bookName NVARCHAR(500) COLLATE Indic_General_90_BIN)

INSERT INTO @Test (bookName)
VALUES (N'தமிழ்')

SELECT *
FROM @Test
WHERE bookName LIKE N'%தமிழ்%'
```

For me, it returns expected results. Perhaps there's issue with your SQL Statement? As I see you're concatenating string to create query, perhaps using [perpared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) would fix your issue?

Comment: No, I still get the special characters... (like &#2.......;) Now, when I paste the exact special character here in the post (i'll edit the question), it gets changed to the result I want. Here it is: &#2980;&#2979;&#3021;&#2979;&#3008;&#2992;&#3021;

The same way, when I fetch these special characters in a jsp page, it displays just fine. But only in DB, I see those as special characters.

Comment: Hey - I've edited my answer. My only thought could be that your text gets translated into hex characters during insertion on your Java client?

Comment: Yes, looks like something hapenning with the text getting translated into hex chars. I just updated th query to include the value directly rather than from the text box, and it just works fine. How can I isoate the hex character conversion in my jsp page? BTW, this is the query that works. String addbks = "insert into something.dbo." + Table + " (ID, BookName, Author, Owner, OwnerEmpID, Status, Reservation, Genre, StatusID) values (NEXT VALUE FOR " + Seq + ", N'பொன்னியின் செல்வன்', N'செல்வன்', '" + Name + "', '" + user2 + "', 'Available', NULL, '" + Genre + "', '1')";

Comment: I cannot answer it, unfortunately. Not enough knowledge.

Comment: Found the answer myself! I was re-directing to a new page after the input and was encoding only the new page. Just added the encoding on the input page as well and this fixed the issue. Thanks so much for your help Evaldas!